# Can there be a "Viewed by OP" Checkbox?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes when answering a question, I want to know if my solution has been viewed. I think getting a notification like, "You're answer to question ABC has been viewed by the OP" or something similar would help me know if my solution failed or the solution hasn't been viewed, especially if a new user is asking the question, who may not know to accept or say how the answer failed.

I want to know if this should be a feature, and if it shouldn't, why not?

Comment: Some people create the account post a question and then promptly forget the password or otherwise don't log in again, but see their answer as a logged out anonymous user. There may be other reasons as well that a user wouldn't be logged in when they view the answers. Such a statistic would be ultimately unreliable.

Comment: Just assume that they have or will.

Comment: What benefit does this information provide? Do you plan to pester OP to read your answer if you don't see a "Viewed by OP" within 3 minutes of posting? What is your planned course of action with such information?

Comment: *would help me know if my solution failed* I don't think it would. Either the box would get checked automatically when the OP looks at the page, which means you still wouldn't know if they actually read and tried your answer or not, or this would be something the OP would have to manually do which would still require the OP knowing how to do so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lots of people view your solution.  Few vote on it.  It doesn't exactly matter if the OP does or does not see your solution again, so long as others who *have* gain insight and valuable information from it.